# Converting Date and time into number of seconds since 1970

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-conversion

I have the date string "2016-04-01T05:00:00+08:00" and I want to convert it into number of seconds since 1 January 1970. I am doing like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *parsingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [parsingFormatter dateFromString:"2016-04-01T05:00:00+08:00"];
NSTimeInterval startTime = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

But in the above example `startTime` returns nil. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I convert it?

Comment: Your date format string is wrong, use this one `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *parsingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [parsingFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-04-01T05:00:00+08:00"];
NSTimeInterval startTime = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

I am getting date "2016-03-31 21:00:00 +0000" UTC format.